# How to center a node / nodes in Graphviz

Tags: graphviz

it is a general question that does not depend on a concrete example:
in graphviz, exists an option that a node / nodes can be automatically centered (vertical & horizontal) in the middle of the output?

EDIT: a "manual" possibilty is given with the `pos` option for a node. but this requires a little bit an adjustment of x and y values. [Graphviz doc to pos](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d%3apos)

Comment: have you looked at twopi or circo?

Answer (score 0):

With `twopi` layout engine you can specify which node you want to put in the center by setting the graph attribute [`root=yourNodeName`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/root/) or node attribute [`yourNodeName [root=true]`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/root/).

Image:
[image: center a node of the graph with graphviz twopi]
and script for node `A` centered:

```
digraph {
    layout=twopi
    root=A

    A -> {B C F G H I J}
    B -> {D E}
}
```

Image:
[image: center a node of the graph with graphviz twopi]
and script for node `E` centered:

```
digraph {
    layout=twopi

    E [root=true]

    A -> {B C F G H I J}
    B -> {D E}
}
```